# Laptop screen only works when connected to external monitor

Tags: boot, laptop, backlight, external-monitor

Once in a while I see the following problem on my HP Envy 17 notebook (2100ed): When I power up, the backlight switches on, but apart from that the screen is black. (No BIOS menu/grub etc, nothing.) Restarting the computer results in the same problem.

I thought there might be something wrong with the laptop screen wiring or something, so I connected an external screen (VGA) monitor to be able to work. Then next day, the laptop screen would work again.

No problem with restarting also. Then sometimes the problem returned. Then I noticed the laptop screen would always start to work again once I connected the external monitor.

Next time the problem returned, I tried using the function key for switching between external and laptop screen. But that had no effect. Only after connecting the external monitor, will the laptop screen go back from black (with backlight on) to normal...

So.. any suggestions what is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with a Toshiba. Somehow the DM got confused as to which was the internal display, so when the external was disconnected it would turn of the internal display.

The fix was to delete the monitor configuration file (monitors.xml). Turn off the computer. Then start with the external disconnected and let the DM recreate it's config file.

the exact location varies depending on desktop, but try /home/(user)/.conf/
replace (user) with your user name.

Comment: Hellø, ok thnx for the suggestion. But the problem already starts before the os is loaded. (boot menu doesn't appear) Did you also see this in your case?

Comment: @user104100 -I don't remember if I has grub, but I didn't have anything after